# Upgrading compose/gradle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I copied project from GitHub and I want to modify it.
But I can't add `LazyHorizontalGrid` so I guess I need to update Jetpack Compose version or Gradle right?
What is proper way of doing that because if I do it with Project Structure as IDE suggest app crashes and I can't even build project.
I googled error and then next one and then next one and so on. But I think that it shouldn't be so hard to just update project.

Answer (score 0):

`LazyHorizontalGrid` was added with [`1.2.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-alpha05) of the Compose Foundation dependency.
To update just change your build.gradle files.

In the root `build.gradle file`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.1'
    }
    //..
    dependencies {
       //...
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"

   }
}
```

In your `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
    //...
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.3.1
        
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    //...all the other compose dependencies
}
```

Check also the [compatibility map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=en) for Compose Compiler Version/Kotlin Version.